# CGridview column button syntax error, unexpected '"'

Tags: javascript, php, yii

This is part of the column located in zii.widgets.grid.CGridView,

```
array(
    'header' => "Action",
    'id' => 'id',
    'name' => 'name',
    'type' => 'raw',
    'value' => 'CHtml::button("Settings", array(
        "onclick" => "document.location.href=\''.Yii::app()->createUrl("/admin/settings/AddEditPaymentSetting/action/edit/eid/".'$data["id"]').'\'",
        "class" => "btn btn-default btn-top-rv btn-block"))',
    'htmlOptions' => array(
       'style' => 'text-align: center;'
    ),
)
```

When I run it on view, that column show 'syntax error, unexpected ""', any idea on this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have some probem with quote sequence  ... try using

```
"onclick" => 
    'document.location.href="' . 
      Yii::app()->createUrl( "/admin/settings/AddEditPaymentSetting/action/edit/eid/" .
           $data["id"] ) . '"'  . "'",
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but it doesn't work, because the quote actually start from CHtml::button, and it doesn't seem like missing quote cause there is no red error show, the syntax error only show on view.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say what your trying to do, but for complex code you should better use anonymous functions for generating value instead string with PHP code.

```
'value' => function ($data) {
    return CHtml::button("Settings", array(
        // your settings
    ));
},
```

Mixing PHP, arrays and JS code in single string is really tricky. I also suggest using some IDE or at least decent editor - with syntax highlighting such errors becomes pretty obvious.